# IB TWS API c# get LmtPrice of Order object

Tags: interactive-brokers, tws

Have Order Id, need code sample how to read order's limit price. Documentation [here](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1Order.html#aef8619178c248a300cf1dd8805f9845e) does not contain any easy-to-go code snippet.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the api? Or do you require a start from scratch approach?

Comment: I do have a solution based on c# tws api sample app with operational connection to tws. This sample app does have a data grid view with active orders, but there is no column with limit price and I failed to find a place in the code where additional field could be added. This order retrieval operates as it is and looks like it cannot be modified anyhow. Sound like I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns for the DataGridView called 'liveOrdersGrid' are added in the designer of IBSampleApp.cs.
The col contents are populated by the class 'OrderManager.cs', inside the method PopulateOrderRow(int rowIndex, OpenOrderMessage orderMessage).

To add a new col containing LMTPrice add a new line such as;
(You need to use the designer and add a 11th col first)

```
private void PopulateOrderRow(int rowIndex, OpenOrderMessage orderMessage)
    {
        liveOrdersGrid[0, rowIndex].Value = Util.IntMaxString(orderMessage.Order.PermId);
        liveOrdersGrid[1, rowIndex].Value = Util.IntMaxString(orderMessage.Order.ClientId);
        liveOrdersGrid[2, rowIndex].Value = Util.IntMaxString(orderMessage.Order.OrderId);
        liveOrdersGrid[3, rowIndex].Value = orderMessage.Order.Account;
        liveOrdersGrid[4, rowIndex].Value = orderMessage.Order.ModelCode;
        liveOrdersGrid[5, rowIndex].Value = orderMessage.Order.Action;
        liveOrdersGrid[6, rowIndex].Value = Util.DecimalMaxString(orderMessage.Order.TotalQuantity);
        liveOrdersGrid[7, rowIndex].Value = orderMessage.Contract.Symbol+" "+orderMessage.Contract.SecType+" "+orderMessage.Contract.Exchange;
        liveOrdersGrid[8, rowIndex].Value = orderMessage.OrderState.Status;
        liveOrdersGrid[9, rowIndex].Value = Util.DoubleMaxString(orderMessage.Order.CashQty);
        // New col at end for LMT Price
        liveOrdersGrid[10, rowIndex].Value = orderMessage.Order.LmtPrice;
    }
```

However before getting too far make sure you double click the line, it opens up a order modify dialog.
[image]

Comment: You are my man, it's exactly what I was looking for!